# Excel Checkbox to call cells via relative referencing

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am trying to create a set of checkboxes that when clicked, will make changes to the cells in the same row as the checkbox is on. To do so, I would have to call the cell location of the checkbox itself. I am not sure how to do that part of the code specifically.

Comment: Thanks to Tim Williams below, but I found another way earlier that fit my purposes better. 

Range(CheckBox1.LinkedCell).Activate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LinkedCell property of the checkbox.

```
CheckBox1.LinkedCell.*etc*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TopLeftCell property to find out where the checkbox is.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    MsgBox CheckBox1.TopLeftCell.Address()
End Sub
```